# Sort a python list of strings with a numeric number

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, numerical

I have a list of filenames called **filelist**

```
 In []: filelist
Out []: ['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']
```

I want to sort this **filelist** by the numerical value that is in the bolded position

> C:\Mon20412\P-2NODE-RAID6-**1**BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx 
>   C:\Mon25312\P-2NODE-RAID6-**13**RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx 
>   C:\Mon20362\P-2NODE-RAID6-**2**GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx

So in this example, the output would be

```
Out []: ['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
         'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx'
         'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']
```

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried extracting the number out of the file path yet? Once you have that, sorting becomes trivial.

Comment: Please provide the code you've tried so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find a good, reliable way to extract the number that you want. Then sort by that number, using the `key` argument. This seems to be reliable enough for your input, but it's not efficient.

```
a = ['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
    'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
    'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']

def k(a):
    x = a.split("\\")[-1].split("-")[3]
    y = filter(lambda x: x in "0123456789", x)
    return int("".join(list(y)))


print(sorted(a, key=k))
```

output:

```
['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx', 
'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import re

f = lambda s: int(re.findall(r'.*RAID6-(\d+).*', s)[0])
sorted(l, key=f)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a regex to parse out the number and use that as a sort key.

Quick and dirty:

```
import re

l = ['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
     'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
     'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']

def get_sort_number(s):
    pattern = r'C:\\Mon\d+\\P-2NODE-RAID6-(\d+)'

    try:
        return int(re.match(pattern, s).group(1))
    except AttributeError:
        return 0

sorted(l, key=get_sort_number)
```

This gives

```
['C:\\Mon20412\\P-2NODE-RAID6-1BLACK-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
 'C:\\Mon20362\\P-2NODE-RAID6-2GREEN-32k-100-segmented.xlsx',
 'C:\\Mon25312\\P-2NODE-RAID6-13RED-32k-100-segmented.xlsx']
```

All strings that cannot be matched by the regex would be at the beginning of the sorted list.